# SQL Server Error - The connection is broken and recovery is not possible

Tags: sql-server, network

I have a .NET application that connects from A Windows 10 client to an SQL Server 2016 Express database running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Whilst a connection is successfully established, it is frequently throwing the following error on subsequent connection attempts:

"The connection is broken and recovery is not possible. The client driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed. Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase the number of recovery attempts."

I have researched this and have not been able to get to the bottom of why this is suddenly occurring after the system has been stable for months.

Comment: Any recent changes to any of the servers involved? Are you sure that no code has been added that could release a connection then try to use it again? Or that a fatal error happened on the SQL side that broke the connection? Finally could the server be getting restarted without your knowledge?

Comment: @RDFozz Yes see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the cause of this was that the server was stuck in a perpetual reboot loop and was losing and regaining connectivity. Power cycling the server resolved the issue.